# Cannot Update SharePoint Publishing Page Image

Tags: 2013, csom

I am trying to update publishing Page image URL but somehow after executing query command, its value saved as null

Below is the code that I am using to update image URL field-

```
ClientContext targetContext = new ClientContext ("REAL URL");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File targetFile = targetContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl ("REAL URL");
var targetPublishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage (targetContext, targetFile.ListItemAllFields);
targetContext.Load (targetPublishingPage.ListItem);
targetContext.ExecuteQuery ();
targetFile.CheckOut ();
targetPublishingPage.ListItem["PublishingPageImage"] = "REAL URL";
targetPublishingPage.ListItem.Update ();
targetContext.ExecuteQuery ();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Question

```
mageFieldValue pageImage = ListItem["PublishingRollupImage"] as ImageFieldValue;
                           string pageImageurl = pageImage.ImageUrl;
                           Image1.ImageUrl = pageImageurl;
```

you may look following link for further details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.fields.imagefieldvalue.imageurl(v=office.14).aspx